# Ubuntu server iso (>14.04) does not install from USB due to network device error

Tags: networking, 16.04, usb

I had to reinstall (from scratch) ubuntu server edition. I have only usb and sd card available (no FDD and no CD/DVD). So I installed the server iso file with UUI to an USB. Everything ok, without errors.
Then at my linux server I bootet from that USB and was able to start installing ubuntu server. After the questions about language and keyboard, the network should be configured, however I always get a message (error) that no network devices are found and can not continue.

I think it is due to the fact that ubuntu (after 2-3 years) is still not able to implement the correct drivers for the JMicron (250) ethernet controller (which I have) and/or to use it properly in the server editions.

That was with v14.04.5 server edition, than I tried the 16.04 server edition and the same error. Than I installed the same way (usb stick) the 16.04 desktop edition and everything is working i.e. I do have internet connection, so network hardware is recognized.

However I do not want to use the desktop version, so my question is:

how to install 16.04 server edition (at USB stick) so that everything will be installed properly (including the driver(s) for the JMicron (jme) 250 Ethernet Controller)?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Ubuntu Server and not the mini ISO?

Comment: Yes, I download the server edition from the release pages: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/

Comment: Do you have a reason to use server? You can install additional server/network tools in Desktop. Plus in the server you may need to setup start the network manually. Desktop and Server are the same under the hood and if you intend to install a desktop environment in the server edition you just defeated its main purpose.